# onActivityForResult not returning any data for Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera-intent

I am having difficulties the video intent triggers fine. I tried to record less than 10 seconds videos and more than 10 seconds. When I debug on Activity for result doesnt return any data.

this is how i trigger the event ...

```
private void record() {
    Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager())!=null){
         new_video_file=getFilePath();
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getActivity(),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",new_video_file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0.5);
        startActivityForResult(intent,VIDEO_REQUEST);

    }
}
```

notice that i want to set to medium quality for video not sure if i need to place 0,5 or 0.5.

Hello i just checked debugging in a pixel 2 XL api 27 and it worked.When i run It in a motorola g 6 running with android 9 it doesnt work

Comment: What you are showing us is what you send to your activity that you are launching.  Not what will get returned.  Wha you put here will be found in your bundle of the activity you are calling.  Any return information will come from what you assign to the bundle in the follow-up activity.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Jay, but i need to get the information or the video in this activity in order to upload it to the  back4app server. I really need to get this video in this activity.Take into consideration that with the pixel 2 XL i got the data but with my phone there was no data in onActivityForResult.

Answer (score 0):

If your `FileProvider` stuff is setup correctly, you should be able to get the video from the Uri that you set as the `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` value.

As a side note, `0.5` is not a valid value for video quality. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore#EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY):

> The name of the Intent-extra used to control the quality of a recorded
>   video. This is an integer property. Currently value 0 means low
>   quality, suitable for MMS messages, and value 1 means high quality. In
>   the future other quality levels may be added.

Furthermore, it's up to camera app devs to respect your quality request, and not all of them do so, in my experience.

Comment: Hello mike i changed the quality to 1, but still the onActivityResult returns null once i record the video.Hello i just checked debugging in a pixel 2 XL api 27 and it worked.When i run It in a motorola g 6 running with android 9 it doesnt work.

Comment: You should not be looking for `Intent.data` to get the captured video file. You should be looking at the Uri that you set in the outgoing request Intent.